# Django Images and contents disappears after some hours

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have build a simple website using django framework,with a blog section to allow staff to write articles and upload an image. unfortunately after a few hours the articles and images will disappear,but when I check on aws s3 bucket,the images are still there.

I have checked on my code and it is okay,the saved functionality is working well.

I expect to have the content on the blog to be there permanently lest deleted from the back end.

Comment: What does "disappear" mean? Do you see `<img>` pointing to a URL that doesn't load? What do you see in the network tab of your browser's devtools?

Comment: http://www.softsearch.co.ke/blog/ , have a look at the blog,I had written some content there yesterday.

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. We're not going to go off-site to find your problem for you, or to dig through code. Questions must be self-contained: _all_ relevant information should be included directly. Please read [ask].

Comment: (Though it sounds like you're losing all of your content, not just images. It looks like your code is running on Elastic Beanstalk? What database are you using?)

Comment: do you by any chance use autoscaler? what is the min number of db instances if so?

Comment: "I have checked on my code and it is okay"—that's a bold claim. Whether the current problem is there or not, hiding your code from us and assuring us that it's perfect is a bad sign. _Always_ suspect your own code.

Comment: @Chris, yes  I am using elastic Beanstalk with the default django sqlite, could that be the issue?

Comment: SQLite is almost certainly the problem. PaaS offerings like Elastic Beanstalk (I'm most familiar with Heroku) rarely offer a persistent filesystem out of the box. And SQLite isn't generally a good production database for Django. I strongly suggest using a proper client-server database like PostgreSQL, both in production and in development. Though you may also be able to store your SQLite file on a persistent filesystem if you really want to. I don't know enough about Elastic Beanstalk to provide proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try a different database.